# Objective-C: pointer arithmetic

Tags: objective-c, arrays, pointers

I need to fill a `dae_prim *array_prim;` where `dae_prim` is a class I created.

I want to use C style because I will pass all those data to OpenGL.

When I'm trying to make a : `mesh->array_prim[i] = mysexyprim` it fails with a "subscript requires size of interface".

I think I understand the problem (Obj-C wants me to use a NSArray) but how can I bypass this?

**More code**

```
class meshes:
@public:
   dae_prim *prims;
   int primcount;
```

.

```
model->meshes->prims = malloc(sizeof(dae_prims*) * model->meshes->primcount);
dae_prim *prims = [[dae_prim alloc]init];
model->meshes->prims[1] = prims; //here is the problem
```

Comment: Most likely you haven't included the header that defines `dae_prim` fully. But you haven't provided much information. (If you're storing Objective-C objects, you should probably use simple C structs to pass data to OpenGL.)

Comment: edited my question with more code
@JeremyRoman no, headers are OK, I can use all the class & its members

Comment: In general, Objective-C class names should be BiCapitalized -- eg, "DaePrim".

Comment: ok...but it's not really my question...

Comment: Have you tried `dae_prim **prims;`?

Comment: @HotLicks I think you didn't get the problem. The problem is making pointer arithmetic on pointer to objects. the problem is here : model->meshes->prims[1] not in the right part of the equal. (dae_prim ? you mean DaePrim ? :p)

Comment: I think I got the problem quite well.  Your declaration is for a pointer to an array of dae_prim, not a pointer to an array of pointers to dae_prim.  But you're trying to assign a pointer to an element of your array -- hence a mismatch.

Comment: @HotLicks: yes, I'm sorry you were right !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a double pointer for meshes->prims, as you want an array of pointers.

```
class meshes:
@public:
   dae_prim **prims; /* a C array of objects pointers */
   int primcount;

model->meshes->prims = malloc(sizeof(dae_prims*) * model->meshes->primcount);
model->meshes->prims[1] = [[dae_prim alloc]init];
```

Cheers.